# What is the lifetime of the Azure's DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration?

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

In my attempts to purge the `DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration` I have tried the following:

- power cycled the (only) webrole instance
- restarted the IIS app pool (via RDP => IIS manager)
- redeployed the web role
- modified the global.asax code => redeploy

But I still see extra copies of `DirectoryConfiguration` members inside the DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration's Directory data sources. These extra copies were accidentally added when the global.asax's `Application_Start()` was called everytime the IIS thread would be retired (20 min idle time). I've copy-pasted the BUGGY code showing how they were added (eventually I got an exception like `OverallQuotaInMB is 150MB but sum of requested sub-quotas is 850MB`).

***Question***: I understand why there are duplicated. However, despite trying the actions in the above bullet list, why isn't the DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration getting purged? Exactly how is it's state being persisted? I can only think it's gotta be Azure table or Azure SQL - but that's just a guess.

```
// called from global.asax's Application_Start()
    public bool Initialize()
    {

        RoleInstanceDiagnosticManager roleInstanceDiagnosticManager = getRoleInstanceDiagnosticManager();
        config = roleInstanceDiagnosticManager.GetCurrentConfiguration();

        if (config == null) 
            config = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();


        LocalResource localResource = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("MyAppLogFolder");
        DirectoryConfiguration dirConfig = new DirectoryConfiguration();
        dirConfig.Container = "myapplog-blob";
        dirConfig.DirectoryQuotaInMB = localResource.MaximumSizeInMegabytes;
        dirConfig.Path = localResource.RootPath;

        // This is a BUG, keeps adding duplicate entries
        config.Directories.DataSources.Add(dirConfig);

        limitOtherDefaultDirSizes(config); // limits overall quota to 150MB
        config.Directories.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10.0);

        roleInstanceDiagnosticManager.SetCurrentConfiguration(config); 

        return true;
    }
```

Remote debugging shows the DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration data structure to be as below. You can clearly see the dups here, warranting the exception.

```
- config    {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration}
-  Directories  {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DirectoriesBufferConfiguration}
-    DataSources Count = 85 System.Collections.Generic.IList<Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DirectoryConfiguration> 
+     [0] {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DirectoryConfiguration}
+     [1] {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DirectoryConfiguration}
+     [2] {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DirectoryConfiguration}
-     [3] {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DirectoryConfiguration}
        Container   "myapplog-blob" string
        DirectoryQuotaInMB  10  int
        Path    "C:\\Resources\\directory\\73c8a6bf9a5e434ab3d0c44034e7b7e9.MyAPP.API.MyAppLogFolder\\" string
-     [4] {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DirectoryConfiguration}   
        Container   "myapplog-blob" string
        DirectoryQuotaInMB  10  int
        Path    "C:\\Resources\\directory\\73c8a6bf9a5e434ab3d0c44034e7b7e9.MyAPP.API.MyAppLogFolder\\" string
+     [5] {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DirectoryConfiguration}   
...
+     [84] {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DirectoryConfiguration}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the following article on MSDN: [Overview of Windows Azure Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh411552.aspx)

> You should consider the following when implementing Windows Azure
>   Diagnostics:
>
> - The configuration information is stored in an XML file in Windows Azure blob storage under
>     **/wad-control-container/deploymentID/rolename/roleinstance**

The configuration is persisted in an XML file in blob storage for the current deployment. In your code you're calling `GetCurrentConfiguration` which will load this XML file. And then you'll keep appending the directory over and over again (which means each recycle will try to add a directory to the current configuration).

`GetCurrentConfiguration` is great when you're trying to modify the settings remote (ie: you want to add some performance counters after the app has been deployed). If you always call **GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();** you'll start with a clean slate.

PS: Try putting this code in the WebRole.cs, that way it will only execute once when your instance starts, and not slow down the application pool each time it starts.

Comment: I would also consider using the diagnostics.wadcfg file to provide default values.  I favor that instead of imperative code in your role.